# How to prevent Double Booking in Apps Script between Google Sheets and Calendar

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, scheduling

I am working on a spreadsheet that will help automate our meeting scheduled. I want to make sure my Team does not put meetings on the same date and time. How do I add this to my existing usable code? (I have not been able to find this answer ANYWHERE!!)

```
function addEvents(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_kdaqhj8lkd7u68s8thinbnjpik@group.calendar.google.com");

  var data = ss.getRange("A2:F"+ lr).getValues();

  for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){

    if(cal.getEvents(data[i][1], data[i][2])==null || cal.getEvents(data[i][1], data[i][2]).length==0 ){

      cal.createEvent(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2],{guests: ''+data[i][3]+','+data[i][4]+'', description:data[i][5]});
}
```

}
}

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
        .addItem('Schedule events now', 'addEvents')
        .addToUi()
```

}

Thank YOU!

Comment: do you mean that you don't want them to add entries/rows into the spreadsheet that have the same date/time? Can you clarify? I was testing your code and it seems it does skip the next events that have intersection with the previous rows

Comment: can you also provide a visualization where "double booking" occurs? Thanks

Comment: I am now getting this Error on my orginal code which was working before this.....11:33:15 AM Error 
Exception: The parameters (String,String) don't match the method signature for CalendarApp.Calendar.getEvents.

Comment: You need to convert the string to Dates.  `getEvents` accepts dates on first 2 parameters. Use `cal.getEvents(new Date(data[i][1]), new Date(data[i][2]))` instead

Comment: Stating same Error

Comment: what specific line causes the error?

Comment: of course now that is working .... but the other On Edit code is stating Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1. (line 38, file "SPED Scheduling")

Comment: I am not sure what you modified. Can you add the code snippet above so I can check the error better. I was expecting that you'd comment the exact line/s of code or add function that caused the error.

Comment: dates = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();

Comment: i'll update my answer, also, please make sure that your sheets all have headers. and data are starting in 2nd row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is similar to what Cooper provided so I'll have this posted instead to help your sheet maintained properly.

I added a behaviour during `onEdit()` in which when a user added an existing set of start and end date in the sheet, the recently added/edited row is automatically deleted.

This can reduce the number of calls to calendar at the expense of constantly checking sheets during edits.

Feel free to use the code below

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var currentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = currentSheet.getActiveCell();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();
  var date, dates, occurences, limit;

  // newly added date in active sheet
  if (cell.getColumn() == 2) { 
    date = [cellValue, cell.offset(0, 1).getValue()];
  }
  else if (cell.getColumn() == 3) {    
    date = [cell.offset(0, -1).getValue(), cellValue];
  }

  // traverse other sheets
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet){
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();

    // dates from other sheets
    dates = sheet.getRange(2, 2, sheet.getLastRow(), 2).getValues();

    occurences = 0;

    // check if dates in other sheets have the newly added date
    for(var index in dates){
      if(JSON.stringify(dates[index]) === JSON.stringify(date)) {
        // increment if found
        occurences++;
      }
    }
    if(sheet.getName() != currentSheet.getName()) {
      // should not occur in other sheets
      limit = 0;
    }
    else {
      // should occur at most once in the active sheet
      limit = 1;
    }
    // if date was found more than the limit
    if (occurences > limit) {
      // prompt user that the newly added date is present in other sheets
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('WARNING!: Dates are already booked in ' + sheetName + '. Deleting newly added event.');

      // delete newly added date
      currentSheet.deleteRow(cell.getRow());
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Any way to make so an alert pops up if a person is adding on the same date/ time that is ALREADY in the sheet...this sheet has 3 tabs for people to input the meetings on and to clarify, I am trying to prevent the same date/time from being added on different tabs in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @DClark, that should be possible, but it may take me some time. I'll update here once answer is updated.

Comment: Hi @DClark, I have update my answer above. Note that this only checks duplicates in other sheets/tabs. It wont check duplicates in the same sheet.

Comment: I'll have to add another condition for that. Do you want it added?

Comment: I have modified the answer to include checks on the current active sheet. @DClark